# Ubuntu doesn't boot because of graphics problem

Tags: 12.04, boot, ati, dual-boot, graphics

While booting my Ubuntu 12.04 I got an error telling my that my graphics is not identified and I have to identify it manually by modifying some configurations.
 And then it allows me the choose from few options :

- **Login with minimal graphics for one session**:
  It shows a finished progress bar, clicking "OK" opens a fullscreen terminal that I can't control, it only shows some process starting and ending(Apache2, bind, etc).
- **troubleshoot the problem** :
  it shows few options(logs, etc) I chose to see a log, walked through it really fast, nothing suspicious. And there was startup logs aswell, which was empty. and finally a reconfigure option which doesn't work.
- **Reconfigure graphics**:
  it shows 2 options, apply generic configurations and use backed-up configurations, since I don't have backed-up configurations, I chose the first one - which didn't work.

I'm using AMD graphics card. I didn't change anything related to graphics card. The last program I installed is FileZilla(I'm not sure though).

The problem is that I don't have any backups, also I installed Ubuntu via Wubi(Dual-booting with Win7), which means I can't access my files to get them and re-install peacefully since I don't have any partitions to access.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, choose the first option and then press CTRL-ALT-F7 to get a GUI. When in a GUI, login, go to System Settings and click Additional Drivers. Then, install the recommended drivers and reboot. If pressing CTRL-ALT-F7 didn't work, pressing CTRL-ALT-F1 will get you to a text terminal (a `tty`).

Comment: I used the second method, since the first one doesn't work. I used `jockey-text` to install the driver, but same result.